LEDs driving at high-side with MOSFETs and PWM
I want to efficiently drive 10 mid-power LEDs (with a 3V forward voltage) in parallel for redundancy purposes, controlling their brightness with PWM at the high side. From what I have seen, there are many options for LED driving, including:
Smart High-Side Switches:
These are mostly NMOS devices with additional functionalities such as fail-short detection, OCP, and charge pumps to drive TTL inputs. While I value the short detection functionality, considering the low voltages and 100-200mA currents involved, I believe they might be overkill. Additionally, I'm unsure about their PWM driving capability due to the presence of charge pumps.
Classic P-Channel Power MOSFET:
This is the simplest approach, utilizing a PMOS configured at the high side with a pull-up on its gate driven by an open-drain MCU GPIO. However, what are the tradeoffs here? Are there more EMI considerations? I understand that I can calibrate the gate resistor values to prevent ringing and control the PWM frequency (perhaps 1-2kHz is suitable) to reduce EMI.
MOSFET Feedback:
Something similar to Figure 8 on page 5 of this TI report: https://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slyy163/slyy163.pdf?ts=1710210982907#page=5
In general, I am seeking redundancy and reliability, as the LEDs won't be operated frequently. What is generally the best option, and what should I pay attention to?

(TI for one does offer multi-channel high side LED drivers. Depending on power supply, consider 2 strings of 5 and 5 strings of 2 in addition to individual LEDs.)

Do you care about efficiency?  Or heat (coolness)?

Is this for an automotive application? The automotive electrical environment is particularly challenging, with large voltage swings.

It is a space application, thus it is very important to have redundancy and a reliable circuit. I wouldn't say that heat is a crucial factor since the circuit is supplied with 3V3.

There isn't any one solution that will be more reliable, it's going to be dependent on the switch and if the switch fails then that's it. It's more likely that the LED's will fail (IMO) than the switch (assuming that you have correct operating specs). Heat can kill components fast so make sure you design with heat in mind. Also make sure the mosfet switchs on and off fast, the faster the better because the less heat dissipation. So reduce capacitance and keep it low on the gate driver.
If you want efficiency use a low side switch with a low Rdson. In general NMOS has low Rdson. NMOS is usually on the low side not the high side. If you want to drive an NMOS on the high side then you must pull the gate higher than the drain, which usually means having a boost circuit or a higher rail than the one attached to the drain of the FET.
The circuits you show are constant current drivers, they dissipate less heat, but more heat than PWM because the FET burns up heat to regulate the current. PWM is fully off or fully on.
Make sure you simulate it and check the heat and make sure the components can handle it
